# How to acknowledge receipt of job offer without sounding like I have decided to accept it yet?

Tags: communication, job-offer, canada

I received a job offer that I am probably going to accept, or negotiate the pay a bit. I once had a bad experience where I received a job offer but the manager went ballistic because he thought I was "missing in action" presumably because I didn't respond fast enough. He even rescinded it for this reason, though I had already told them I had turned it down.

How should I send an acknowledgment that I received the offer and am reviewing it and thinking about it. Just

> Thanks, received.

The job offer doesn't have an expiration date, but from what I read 24-48 hours is normal? If I received it mid-morning Thursday is it OK if I have a response by Monday or is that too late?

Comment: Can you simply ask the company when is the latest that you have to give them the answer ?

Comment: You probably realise it, too, but you dodged a bullet with that boss. o_O

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to acknowledge receipt of job offer without sounding like I have decided to accept it yet?

Unless you plan to wait an extraordinary long time before letting them know if you accept/decline, there is no need to acknowledge their offer.  Simply respond to their offer with your decision within a reasonable amount of time and you will be fine (24-48 hours should be enough).  If you need to take more time to make your decision you can send an acknowledgement and explain your situation:

> Thank you for the offer, I am reviewing the offer and will let you know my decision by X date.

Your previous experience with the ballistic manager is definitely not the norm and should not be used to gauge how most companies conduct business.

Answer (score 6):

You could respond simply as:

"I have received your offer and am currently considering it.  I will let you know of my decision by xx/xx/xxxx."

If you have any questions or wish to negotiate terms, you should do that sooner rather than later.